# How to fight with mold on wall and ceiling connection on last floor

Tags: walls, ceiling, mold, humidity, fungus

I live in a 4 store old (from about 1930's) building. Occasionally (in autumn, winter or spring) all gable walls have mold/mould/fungus in the wall and ceiling connection. Under my flat there's only roof (no other floors or attic).

Wall is facing east, it's standard brick wall with no special insulation. Plaster is partially already shattered and off.

How to fight with that mold?

EDIT: I bought hygrometer and it shows 70% @ 22°C, and i peak even 82% (at night in bedroom)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you live and the rights as a renter, this seems like something that should be taken up with the building owner. You can certainly attempt mitigation, but from personal and anecdotal experience, mold growth that shows up in living areas, is usually a sign of much worse mold behind those visible surfaces.

Often times this would require mold mitigation up to and including removal of interior drywall/plaster, removal and treatment of mold growing on the internals of the structure, added ventilation and treatment of the problems causing mold growth, and the reinstallation of mold/mildew resistant materials.

This sounds like a bigger job than just removing the superficial presence.

**Remember, just because you cannot see the mold, does not mean that it is not affecting your health or your property**

I encourage you to take this seriously and have this issue corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use an EPA approved moldicide like [MoldSTAT Plus](http://theochem.com/uploads/Tech%20Bulletins/Moldstat%20Plus%20TB%20100352.pdf)

Spray this on the surface, brush gently to remove surface mold, spray again.